# JQuery - Get parent of parent by class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `<textarea>` within a `<div>` which is contained within another `<div>`.  The `<textarea>` has an ID which I can reference, however neither of the `<div>`'s have ID's.  They do however always have a set class.  There can be multiple of these on the same page, only the `<textarea>` ID is unique:

```
<div class = "grandparent">
  <div class = "parent">
    <textarea id = "id_1"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<div class = "grandparent">
  <div class = "parent">
    <textarea id = "id_2"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not able to change this structure.  Is it possible for me to style the grandparent `<div>` via JQuery?

Edit: To clarify, I only want to style the grandparent of a particular `<textarea>`

Comment: you mean all the grandparent div or just a particular one?

Comment: Whoops sorry - just the grandparent of a particular one - I'll update the question

Comment: @Oscar Bout beated me on time, https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/fee0sk2t/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[source: https://api.jquery.com/parent/](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

so it should be:

```
$( "#id_1" ).parent().parent().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'll accept when time allows.  I tried .parent() but didn't realise you could use it twice, so simple when you know how.  Thanks!

Comment: @Lee `.closest()` is better choice as you don't have to traverse up two times and `.parent()` is a bit on slower side, so be careful if markup is lengthy and +1 to Oscar.

Answer (score 9):

you can use [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), it will selects the first element that matches the selector, up from the DOM tree.

```
$( "#id_1" ).closest('.grandparent').css( "background-color", "red" );
```

***[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ufLspeLt/)***

Comment: in my opinion better answer